# angular2 routing redirectTo when url doesn't exist

Tags: angular

Is there a way to redirect the user back to home page when they try to access non-existent url like /randomUrl.

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
 { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
];
```

I thought it would be something like the code below, but its not redirect back to the main page.

```
{path: '/**', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

full route.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/component/login';
import { AuthGuard } from './authguard';
import { JourneysComponent } from '../journeys/components/journeys';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  {path:  '**', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'journeys', component: JourneysComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }

];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

Comment: Have you tried without `pathMatch`? You might need to add the `/**` redirect route on child routes as well. Do you get any error in the browser console?

Comment: Yeah I get invalid route /**, oh because it should start with slash, but its not redirecting anywhere

Comment: I think `/` should be removed from `'/**'` - just `'**'`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah i've just removed that

Comment: Yeah it did :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
{path: '/**', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

to

```
{path: '**', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

The paths should not contain leading `/`

Comment: Hah now it doesn't let me go to any existing paths. it stays on the default page.

Comment: I think you need to add `pathMatch: full` to the `''` route. Hard to tell otherwise because there is so little information about your setup.

Comment: You can also try to move the `**` route last but AFAIK the order of routes shouldn't matter anymore in recent router versions.

Comment: I've added my routing.ts in my original post above. So if url doesn't exist it should redirect to the loginComponent which is just the ' ' in my case as that's the default.

Comment: Have you checked your routing setup works as expected without the `**` route (when you only use valid URLs)?

Comment: Yeah all routing paths are working, without this thing I'm trying to do atm.

Comment: Fixed this now, the '**' should be in the last of the paths as angular checks the path from top to bottom. But is it possible to redirectTo: 'previous page' instead of default page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121251/discussion-between-gunter-zochbauer-and-ncore).

Comment: You could try using a guard or add a component instead of the redirect and call `location.back()` there (inject `location:Location`)

Comment: Yeah just thought of using component, but problem is what if a user is outside the app aha it will just redirect them back to whatever url they were on.

Comment: I see. You would need to check the previous URL first.